# PHP + JSON - Handling different outputs (error & success)

Tags: php, json

To keep things simple, I call an API using file_get_contents(url with parameters), I then decode what comes back.

If the call is successful, I get a response back like the following:

```
Array ( 
[data] => Array ( 
    [internalName] => nemonorm 
    [name] => nemonorm 
    [acctId] => 28685607 
    [profileIconId] => 544 
    [revisionDate] => /Date(1361354064000)/ 
    [summonerLevel] => 30 
    [summonerId] => 24286314 
) 
[success] => 1
```

)

I can grab that data.  However if the API can't find the username (which is passed in the parameter), then it responds with the following:

```
Array ( 
      [success] => [error] => Summoner RandomName was not found.
)
```

My question is, how do I tell whether it was a successful reply (first response), or comes back with the error (second response) correctly?

Comment: if ($response['success']==1) or if (!empty($response['data']))

Comment: Is that Elophant API ? :)

Comment: Yes :D trying to implement it into my PHPBB forums properly, with caching and stuff so I have to call the API as little as possible, but with proper error messages and stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$var = file_get_contents(...);
if($var['success'])
    echo 'success';
else
    echo 'fail';
```